# how to use playwright with plugin (like stylus, a chrome plugin)

Tags: plugins, playwright

I am using chromium.launchPersistentContext to open a head chrome. I want to use plugins, like stylus, that change the css of the page. Why chrome plugins does not appear with my local chrome instance ? I can see the bookmark, have the session saved, but no plugins appearing. Any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Extensions only work in Chrome / Chromium in non-headless mode, launched with a persistent context.`

Are you using headless mode?

or have you tried `--load-extension`?

https://playwright.dev/docs/chrome-extensions

Answer (score 0):

You should add arg --disable-extensions-except first, so that chrome will allow the extension.

It will be like : `--disable-extensions-except=Extensions\\qbot-capture-chrome-v1.50.0_38456_1511931899`